# How to generate a new Xauthority with no home?

Tags: ssh, x11, xauth

I have been given access to a system where I have no home folder.  I've asked the administrator to create a home folder for me but due to some complexity he is unable to.

Therefore, I have no .Xauthority file and I cannot open a X11 gui.
Is there a way for me to regenerate a .Xauthority file after login without root priv?  I can change my env HOME and XAUTHORITY variable to a folder in /tmp however I don't know how to create a .Xauthority.  I tried "xauth generate :10 . trusted" but it says "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication."

Comment: Since the default for XAUTHORITY is $HOME/.Xauthority, don't you need to set it to a *file* in `/tmp`? As long as the parent directory exists and is writeable it shouldn't be necessary for the file to pre-exist AFAIK

Comment: How do you login (ssh)? Which X server do you wish to connect to? The one running on the host where you execute ssh? What's the content of `HOME`? Can you set `HOME` to `/tmp/mydir` or something? Note that `.Xauthority` is a *shared secret* between the X server you want to connect to and you as a user. You can't just generate your own.

Comment: I am connecting via SSH to the server where I dont have a home folder from my client (running cygwin).  I want to be able to connect back to the cygwin X server over SSH.  There is no content in HOME because HOME does not exist.  I can set HOME to /tmp/mydir but only AFTER login.  I understand that .Xauthority is a "shared secret" but doesn't it  get generated at login?  I had hoped I could rerun whatever program generates that file (after I have set HOME or XAUTHORITY to /tmp/mydir)